# Is there any way to redirect stdout to a variable as a string in q, or otherwise stringify a variable?

Tags: kdb

Right now I can use `0N!x` or `show x` to print `x` (which is not a string) to stdout. Is there any way for this output to be obtained by the q process as a string variable, rather than printing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE based on your comment, you can use `-3!` or `.Q.s1` (same thing) to stringify

```
q)-3!(`abc;123)
"(`abc;123)"

q).Q.s1 (.z.P;"comment")
"(2019.06.21D16:14:47.825294000;\"comment\")"
```

Original answer: You can capture the variable before `show` or for `0N!` you can capture it before and after

```
q)show a:"abc"
"abc"
q)
q)a
"abc"
q)
q)b:0N!"abc"
"abc"
q)b
"abc"
q)
q)0N!c:"abc"
"abc"
"abc"
q)c
"abc"
q)
q)d:show "abc"
"abc"
q)
q)d
q)
```

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. The variable being printed is not a string. I would like to capture what is being printed as a string.

Comment: It should be noted that `.Q.s1` and `![-3]` are both limited by the current value of `system "c"`, which has a maximum value of 1997 for both rows and columns.